# Perform CRUD actions for related resources on the same page in React Admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm using React Admin to create a delivery route system, where each delivery route has a number of delivery route stops. The database tables look like the below

```
Table: delivery_routes
Columns: id, name


Table: delivery_routes_stops
Columns: id, name, delivery_route_id, latitude, longitude
```

I have a resource in React Admin called 'Delivery Routes' which provides an edit action for each `delivery_routes` record in the database. When information is saved on the page, a RESTful API request is sent to `/api/delivery-routes/{delivery_route_id}`.

The edit page also contains an instance of Google Maps, which allows users to drop markers. Each of these makers will refer to a related `delivery_routes_stop` record. I need React Admin to perform CRUD actions against the markers as soon as the action takes place, rather than on explicit save and I also need React Admin to perform all CRUD actions all on the same page for the related record.

Example:

- A user clicks on a delivery route record, which opens the edit page
- The user creates a new marker on the Google Maps instance.
- React Admin makes a POST request to `/api/delivery-routes/{delivery_route_id}/delivery-routes-stops`, sending the marker data in the request.
- The user then drags the marker to a new location
- React Admin makes a PATCH request to `/api/delivery-routes/{delivery_route_id}/delivery-routes-stops/{delivery_routes_stops_id}`
- The user then decides to delete the marker
- React Admin makes a DELETE request to `/api/delivery-routes/{delivery_route_id}/delivery-routes-stops/{delivery_routes_stops_id}`

Answer (score 1):

React-admin has a number of primitives for nested forms. In your case, can a `ReferenceManyInput` solve your problem?

Example usage:

```
import {
    Edit,
    SimpleForm,
    TextInput,
    NumberInput,
    ReferenceInput,
    SelectInput,
} from 'react-admin';
import { ReferenceManyInput } from '@react-admin/ra-relationships';

const ProductEdit = () => (
    <Edit mutationMode="optimistic">
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <NumberInput source="price" />
            <ReferenceInput source="category_id" reference="categories" />
            <ReferenceManyInput reference="variants" target="product_id">
                <SimpleFormIterator inline>
                    <TextInput source="sku" />
                    <SelectInput source="size" choices={sizes} />
                    <SelectInput source="color" choices={colors} />
                    <NumberInput source="stock" defaultValue={0} />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ReferenceManyInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/EditTutorial.html#nested-forms